# Draw a line in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Using XML layout, you could use a View object with colored background to draw a line.

```xml
<View
   android:width="match_parent"
   android:height="1dp"
   android:background="#000000" />
```

How can we **draw a** horizontal or vertical **line in Jetpack compose**?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You can use

> Divider Composable

method for **Horizontal** line like below.

```
Divider(color = Color.Blue, thickness = 1.dp)
```

Example :

```
@Composable
fun drawLine(){
    MaterialTheme {

        VerticalScroller{
            Column(modifier = Spacing(16.dp), mainAxisSize = LayoutSize.Expand) {

                (0..3).forEachIndexed { index, i ->
                    Text(
                        text = "Draw Line !",
                        style = TextStyle(color = Color.DarkGray, fontSize = 22.sp)
                    )

                    Divider(color = Color.Blue, thickness = 2.dp)

                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `Divider`'s `height` parameter has been renamed to `thickness`

Comment: What if we do not want it to fit the entire width? I just want a fixed width and fixed thickness line, which I want to be interactive by gestures.

Comment: @MARSK then just use a coloured box, which is what `Divider` does internally - it's a super simple wrapper composable:
`Box(modifier.then(indentMod).fillMaxWidth().height(thickness).background(color = color))`

Answer (score 43):

To draw a line you can use the built-in [androidx.compose.material.Divider](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary?hl=en#divider) if you use [androidx.compose.material](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material) or create your own using the same approach that the material divider does:

### Horizontal line

```kotlin
Column(
    // forces the column to be as wide as the widest child,
    // use .fillMaxWidth() to fill the parent instead
    // https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layout#intrinsic-measurements
    modifier = Modifier.width(IntrinsicSize.Max)
) {
    Text("one", Modifier.padding(4.dp))

    // use the material divider
    Divider(color = Color.Red, thickness = 1.dp)

    Text("two", Modifier.padding(4.dp))

    // or replace it with a custom one
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(1.dp)
            .background(color = Color.Red)
    )

    Text("three", Modifier.padding(4.dp))
}
```

[image]

### Vertical line

```kotlin
Row(
    // forces the row to be as tall as the tallest child,
    // use .fillMaxHeight() to fill the parent instead
    // https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layout#intrinsic-measurements
    modifier = Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
) {
    Text("one", Modifier.padding(4.dp))

    // use the material divider
    Divider(
        color = Color.Red,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .width(1.dp)
    )

    Text("two", Modifier.padding(4.dp))

    // or replace it with a custom one
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .width(1.dp)
            .background(color = Color.Red)
    )

    Text("three", Modifier.padding(4.dp))
}
```

[image]